# Getting AccessDenied error while upgrading EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks

I am trying to upgrade my EKS cluster from 1.15 to 1.16 using same ci pipeline which created the cluster...So the credentials have no issue.However I am receiving AccessDenied error.I am using    **eksctl upgrade cluster**  command to upgrade cluster.

```
    info: cluster test-cluster exists, will upgrade it
    [ℹ]  eksctl version 0.33.0
    [ℹ]  using region us-east-1
    [!]  NOTE: cluster VPC (subnets, routing & NAT Gateway) configuration changes are not yet implemented
    [ℹ]  will upgrade cluster "test-cluster" control plane from current version "1.15" to "1.16"
    Error: AccessDeniedException: 
        status code: 403, request id: 1a02b0fd-dca5-4e54-9950-da29cac2cea9
```

My eksctl version 0.33.0

I am not sure why the same ci pipeline which created the cluster now throwing Access denied error when trying to upgrade the cluster..Is there any permissions I need to add to IAM policy for the user ? I dont find anything in the prerequisites document.So Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the error was due to  missing IAM permission.
I used --verbose 5 to diagnose this issue.